# Rust using chain after String.split

Tags: rust

I have this piece of code that works:

```rust
for line in content
    .split('\n')
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .iter()
    .chain((&["output"]).iter())
```

I think there must be a way to use the iterator provided by split to obtain the same result without having to collect() into a vector.

When I try to change `.collect::<Vec<_>>().iter()` to `into_iter()` I get the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str> as IntoIterator>::Item == &str`
   --> src/main.rs:251:53
    |
251 |         for line in content.split('\n').into_iter().chain((&["output"]).iter()) {
    |                                                     ^^^^^ expected `&str`, found `str`
    |
    = note: expected reference `&&str`
               found reference `&str`
```

There are also other errors referring to the same line that basically say the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of the problem is:

- `(&["output"]).iter()` is type `std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>` which has `Item=&&str`.
- `content.split('\n')` is type `std::str::Split<'_, char>` which has `Item=&str`.

So the item types do not match. If you make the types match it compiles, IMO the easiest is to use map on the array to dereference each string.

```
    for line in content
        .split('\n')
        .chain((&["output"]).iter().map(|s|*s)) {
            println!("line={}",line);
       }
```

---

I found this by inserting lines of the form `let q:() = ...` which gave me

```
21 |     let q:() = (&["output"]).iter();   
   |           --   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found struct `std::slice::Iter`
   |           |
   |           expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>`
```

```
22 |     let q:() = content.split('\n');
   |           --   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found struct `std::str::Split`
   |           |
   |           expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `std::str::Split<'_, char>`
```

Then followed these up by `let q: <X as Iterator>::Item = ()`

```
23 |     let q: <std::slice::Iter<&str> as Iterator>::Item = ();
   |            ------------------------------------------   ^^ expected `&&str`, found `()`
```

and

```
24 |     let q: <std::str::Split<char> as Iterator>::Item = ();
   |            -----------------------------------------   ^^ expected `&str`, found `()`
```

Comment: I though dereferencing was the solution but I hadn't figured out how to do it. I tried dereferencing the str inside de array like this: `(&[*"output"]).iter()` but the compiler said that the trait bound `str: Sized` was not satisfied. Didn't think to use map to dereference it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't quite understand where the second layer of references comes from.

Comment: If you need only a single element in the second iterator you can use [`std::iter::once("output")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html) or `Some("output")`, both impl `IntoIterator<Item=&str>`.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `.map(|s| *s)` to unwrap un unnecessary reference, you can use `.copied()`.